# Is it possible to typedef union inside a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef, unions

I don't really understand how union works. Can somebody explain how it works? Can I typedef the union? If the answer is yes, how can i do that? What is the problem with this code below?

```c
typedef struct Car{
        int age;
        int weight;

        enum Type { Tesla, Lada } type;

        typedef union Consumption{
                double litre;
                int kwh;
        } Consumption;

        Consumption consumption;
} Car;
```

error code when i try to compile this code:

```
union1.c:9:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘typedef’
  typedef union Consumption{
  ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: Why try? C doesn't have the notion of scoping required to access that union, even if you could define it. It'll just end up being external to `Car`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `typedef` cannot exist inside of a `struct` or `union`.  That doesn't mean however that you can't define a `struct` or `union` inside of another.  For example:

```
typedef struct Car{
        int age;
        int weight;

        enum Type { Tesla, Lada } type;

        union Consumption{
                double litre;
                int kwh;
        } consumption;
} Car;
```